# Spring custom authentication filter and provider not invoking controller method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

I'm trying to implement a custom authentication logic with latest version of Spring Boot, Web and Security, but I'm struggling with some issues. I was trying out many solutions in similar questions/tutorials without success or understanding what actually happens.

I'm creating a REST application with stateless authentication, i.e. there is a REST endpoint (/web/auth/login) that expects username and password and returns a string token, which is then used in all the other REST endpoints (/api/**) to identify the user. I need to implement a custom solution as authentication will become more complex in the future and I would like to understand the basics of Spring Security.

To achieve the token authentication, I'm creating a customized filter and provider:

The filter:

```
public class TokenAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

public TokenAuthenticationFilter() {
    super(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/**", "GET"));
}

@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
    String token = request.getParameter("token");
    if (token == null || token.length() == 0) {
        throw new BadCredentialsException("Missing token");
    }

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(token, null);

    return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authenticationToken);
}
}
```

The provider:

```
@Component
public class TokenAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
@Autowired
private AuthenticationTokenManager tokenManager;

@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    String token = (String)authentication.getPrincipal();
    return tokenManager.getAuthenticationByToken(token);
}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.equals(authentication);
}
}
```

The config:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(1)
public class TokenAuthenticationSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Autowired
private TokenAuthenticationProvider authProvider;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.antMatcher("/api/**")
    .csrf().disable()
    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
    .and().addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
}

@Bean
public TokenAuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter() throws Exception {
    TokenAuthenticationFilter tokenProcessingFilter = new TokenAuthenticationFilter();
    tokenProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
    return tokenProcessingFilter;
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
}
}
```

The AuthenticationTokenManager used in the provider (and also in the login process):

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationTokenManager {
private Map<String, AuthenticationToken> tokens;

public AuthenticationTokenManager() {
    tokens = new HashMap<>();
}

private String generateToken(AuthenticationToken authentication) {
    return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
}

public String addAuthentication(AuthenticationToken authentication) {
    String token = generateToken(authentication);
    tokens.put(token, authentication);
    return token;
}

public AuthenticationToken getAuthenticationByToken(String token) {
    return tokens.get(token);
}
```

}

**What happens:**
I'm appending a valid token in the request to "/api/bla" (which is a REST controller returning some Json). The filter and provider both get invoked. **The problem is**, the browser is redirected to "/" instead of invoking the REST controller's requested method. This seems to happen in SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler, but why is this handler being used?

**I tried**

- to implement an empty success handler, resulting in a 200 status code and still not invoking the controller
- to do authentication in a simple GenericFilterBean and setting the authentication object via SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication) which results in a "Bad credentials" error page.

I would like to understand why my controller is not being called after I authenticated the token. Besides that, is there a "Spring" way to store the token instead of storing it in a Map, like a custom implementation of SecurityContextRepository?

I really appreciate any hint!

Comment: Any working solution for this? We have the same problem, and any hint or working code would be nice.

Answer (score 4):

Might be a little late but I was having the same problem and adding:

```
@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication(
        final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response,
        final FilterChain chain, final Authentication authResult)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

to my AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter implementation did the trick.

Comment: Instead of replacing the implementation, I would recommend calling super first

Answer (score 0):

Use setContinueChainBeforeSuccessfulAuthentication(true) in constructor